# warning: passing argument 1 of 'generarArreglo' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]| en C

Tags: c

Tengo un programa el cual pretende que un usuario pueda generar un arreglo, cuya cantidad máxima de elementos está definida con una constante (MAXARREGLO = 21), y luego imprima los asteriscos correspondientes al valor de cada elemento del arreglo.

El error que especifiqué en el título, aparece en las líneas 10 y 11 del siguiente código (últimas dos líneas del main):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXARREGLO 21
void generarArreglo(int []);
void imprimirArregloCodificado(int []);

int main()
{
    int arreglo[MAXARREGLO];
    generarArreglo(arreglo[MAXARREGLO]);
    imprimirArregloCodificado(arreglo[MAXARREGLO]);
}

void generarArreglo(int arreglo[MAXARREGLO])
{
    int i, aux=1;
    printf("\nSe le solicitaran %d valores para el arreglo.", MAXARREGLO);
    printf("\nPuede introducir cualquier numero negativo para finalizar antes de tiempo.");
    while (aux >= 0)
    {
        for (i = 0; i <= MAXARREGLO; i++)
        {
            printf("\nIngrese un valor para el espacio %d del arreglo: ", i);
            scanf("%d", &aux);

            if (aux >= 0)
            {
                arreglo[i] = aux;
            }
            else if (arreglo < 0)
            //Si el último arreglo introducido finaliza el programa, se reduce i en uno
            {
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}

void imprimirArregloCodificado(int arreglo[MAXARREGLO])
{
    int i, aux;
    for (i = 0; i <= MAXARREGLO; i++)
    {
        if (arreglo[i] >= 1)
        {
            aux = arreglo[i];
            printf("\n%d ---> ", aux);
            for (aux; aux >= 0; aux--)
            {
                printf("*");
            }
        }
        else if (arreglo[i] == 0)
        {
            printf("\n%d ---> ", aux);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tu fallo es que pasas un elemento del arreglo y no el arreglo que además el elemento pasado está fuera de rango ya que los elementos o índices del array van desde 0 hasta MAXARREGLO-1.
La función corregida sería así:

```
int main()
{
    int arreglo[MAXARREGLO];

    generarArreglo(arreglo);
    imprimirArregloCodificado(arreglo);
}
```

Además la función generarArreglo e imprimirArregloCodificado tendrían que llevar como parámetro:

```
void generarArreglo(int arreglo[])
{
    ...
}

void imprimirArregloCodificado(int arreglo[])
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: *Además la función generarArreglo e ... tendrían que llevar como parámetro...* La forma como declaró el OP los parámetros están bien, es código válido de C, simplemente  es innecesario. Al fin de cuenta, el parámetro en realidad no es un *array*, sino, un puntero a `int` (esta conversión lo hace el compilador de forma implícita).

Comment: Pues llevas razón y creo que fue eso precisamente lo que indujo el error que cometía pasando un entero en lugar del array.

Comment: Gracias Antonio. Lo primero que me comentaste acerca de pasar el arreglo, y no solo un elemento del arreglo, funcionó perfectamente. Con eso el programa ya empezó a funcionar.

Comment: Lo segundo que me comentaste también lo probé, y como dice MrDave, funciona de ambas formas el programa correctamente, la aclaración que hice simplemente es innecesaria. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

En estas dos líneas:

```c
generarArreglo(arreglo[MAXARREGLO]);
imprimirArregloCodificado(arreglo[MAXARREGLO]);
```

Ocurrirá un [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer) (pasarse de los límites del **array**), ya que el *array* empieza desde `0` a `MAXARREGLO-1` y luego le estarías pasando al parámetro un entero en la cual coincide con una *dirección de memoria*, que posteriormente, la función intentará acceder a ella y ahí es donde ocasionará un [fallo de segmentación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso) (acceder a memoria que no le pertenece al programa). Con esto haces que posiblemente el programa termine su ejecución.

**Solución:**

Debes pasar la dirección de memoria del primer elemento del *array*:

```c
generarArreglo(arreglo);
imprimirArregloCodificado(arreglo);
```

**Nota:** Realmente no pasas el arreglo como tal, simplemente se pasa una dirección de memoria, ya que el identificador `arreglo` es un simple alias de la dirección base del *array*.

El código de arriba es equivalente a esto:

```c
generarArreglo(&arreglo[0]);
imprimirArregloCodificado(&arreglo[0]);
```

Otro error es la forma como recorres el *array*:

```c
for (i = 0; i <= MAXARREGLO; i++)
```

Ahí estarías desbordando el búfer nuevamente. La variable `i` solo debe tomar valores que estén en el rango de `0` a `20` (en este caso, claro).

La forma correcta sería así:

```c
for (i = 0; i < MAXARREGLO; i++)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda MrDave, me anoté todo lo que me dijiste para tener en cuenta a posteriori. También lo que me comentaste me ayudó a solucionar el problema que tenía en otro programa, aunque la solución definitiva es la respuesta por Antonio.

Comment: @JuanPabloFrersCampos ¡De nada! Me da gusto que pudiste solucionar el problema.